# Where did the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" go?

Tags: docker

I've reinstalled Docker for Mac, am I not supposed to see "Docker Quickstart Terminal", or are things handled differently now?

Comment: Docker for Mac or Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely used to have "Docker Toolbox", which is VM based, and came with the Quickstart Terminal, which runs `docker-machine` and boots into a VM.

The latest "Docker for Mac"  installation is a "native" installation (doesn't require VirtualBox), so you don't need a Quickstart terminal. Your regular Terminal app has `docker` commands immediately available (assuming Docker daemon is running)

More details can be found at Docker FAQ

Comment: Do i still have to create a virtual machine? Or can i just get going?

Comment: Technically, it's a hypervisor now, so a smaller VM, but you don't need to worry about those details. Just start pulling images